# Why doesn't Helium behave as an ideal gas?

Tags: ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, inert-gases

I am a bit confused (might be due to some conceptual misunderstanding) as to why doesn't Helium behave as an ideal gas (it shows a deviation from the $pV$ vs $p$ graph)? (Given the fact that it is highly inert therefore there is no attraction between the molecules.)

Here is the graph for reference :

[image: pV vs p graph of Helium and other gases]

Comment: Can you show the graph?

Comment: @David I have uploaded the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A substance being inert does not mean that it doesn't have forces of attraction or repulsion, or even that the collisions undergone by gas molecules are elastic. It is true that helium gas is quite inert, but there still are Van der Waals' interactions present in helium, moreover the gas particles are not exactly point sized which the kinetic theory assumes gases to be. Hence there is deviation from ideal gas behaviour.

Comment: Wait, real gases undergo inelastic collisions???

Comment: @aditya_stack Depends on the temperature and the nature of the molecules.  It is more experimentally observable in the form of the stair-step like dependence of specific heat on temperature.

Comment: @dmckee Is there somewhere I can read more about this? Also what term of the VWR eqn, if any, accounts for inelastic collisions?

Comment: @aditya This effect doesn’t show up in the equation of state because the EOS relates pressure, volume, and *temperature* while the specific heat relates temperature to internal energy. Start with the Wikipedia article on the equipartition theorem (and the section on diatomic gasses in particular).

Answer (score 1):

Helium may have negligible interactions, but it still has a non-zero volume.   As you compress the pressure, the space available for the atoms to occupy does not decrease linearly.

An ideal gas would have components that occupy zero volume.  So each component would have collisions only with the sides of the container.

The molecules of a real gas occupy a volume. This volume reduces the effective volume of the container, which means collisions happen more often and the pressure is greater than would be expected from an ideal gas.  The smaller the molecule/atom/component, the lower the slope on the graph.

Comment: Presumptively one can extract the van der Waals volume terms from the slope of the graph if this is the proper explanation.

Comment: @BowlOfRed should the VWR eqn for He then be P(V-nb)=nRT as attraction is negligible (inert nature) but repulsion is not (large atomic size) ?

Comment: You can always simplify whenever the conditions allow.  At low pressures and high temperatures, the ideal gas law is usually sufficient, while at low enough temperatures, conditions are far from that and the equation is not useful.  It's just that in the region indicated on the graph in the question, the interatomic forces are small enough to not matter much and not relevant to the deviation.  It doesn't mean they can be ignored in other conditions.